# Ошибка KeyError

Tags: python-3.x, json, requests

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import date
URL = r'http://api.nobelprize.org/v1/prize.json'
print(requests.get(URL).json()['prizes'][0]['year'])
print(requests.get(URL).json()['prizes'][0]['category'])
print(requests.get(URL).json()['prizes'][0]['laureates'])
print(requests.get(URL).json()['prizes'][0]['laureates'][1]['surname'])
print(requests.get(URL).json()['prizes'][0].keys())

print([i['year']  for i in requests.get(URL).json()['prizes']])
print([i['laureates']  for i in requests.get(URL).json()['prizes']])
```

Почему в последней строчке возникает ошибка KeyError: 'laureates'?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще задание такое. Нужно написать программу

```
def parse_nobel_json(year):
    """ Используя json базу данных лауреатов Нобелевской премии вернуть 
    `[winner1, ...]` - список фамилий лауреатов Нобелевской премии по физике в году `year`
Если в json нет данных за запрашиваемый год, то вернуть `None`

Аргументы:
    - year:int - год вручения Нобелевской премии

Возвращает:
    - list: список нобелевских лауреатов

Пример:
>>> parse_nobel_json(2018)
['Ashkin', 'Mourou', 'Strickland']

Указания:
    - json база лежит по адресу http://api.nobelprize.org/v1/prize.json
    - получить ответ на запрос можно с помощью requests.get
    - обработать ответ можно с помощью json
    - авторское решение занимает 5 строк
"""
```

Comment: Ошибка KeyError возникает по одной единственной причине.

Comment: "Согласно официальной документации Python 3, ошибка KeyError возникает, когда  ключ набора (словаря) не найден в наборе существующих ключей."
Но ключ в моём случае есть.

Comment: Если питон выдал ошибку KeyError, значит вы ошибаетесь и ключа на самом деле нету

Comment: Ну, в нулевом элементе ключ есть. Но в каком-то другом - нет. Вы же только нулевой распечатали "на посмотреть".

Comment: И безотносительно вопроса:  вы в коде семь раз запрашиваете одно и то же. Это нехорошо. Нужно запросить один раз и сохранить в переменную.

Comment: Например, там есть такие записи `{'year': '1939', 'category': 'peace', 'overallMotivation': '"No Nobel Prize was awarded this year. The prize money was with 1/3 allocated to the Main Fund and with 2/3 to the Special Fund of this prize section."'}`. И, соответственно, там нет никаких лауреатов.

Comment: Спасибо! Стало ясно, почему ошибка возникает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем за помощь! Задачу решил.

```
def parse_nobel_json(year):
    import requests
    import json
    laureates = []
    URL = r'http://api.nobelprize.org/v1/prize.json'
    jsonObj = requests.get(URL).json()
    for prize in jsonObj['prizes']:
        if prize['year'] == str(year) and prize.get('laureates') != None and prize['category'] =="physics":
            for laureate in prize['laureates']:
              if (laureate.get('surname') != None):
                laureates.append(laureate['surname'])
              else:
                laureates.append(laureate['firstname'])
    return laureates if len(laureates) != 0 else None
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Видимо есть такой ключ существует не во всех элементах списка, используй метод get:

```
[i.get('year', 'Year not found!')  for i in requests.get(URL).json()['prizes']]
```